# Бесконечный скролинг с удалением предыдущей инфы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код:

```
$sdvig = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
$scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if  ($scroll == $sdvig) 
    {
        $page = +$page + 20;
        if($n==0){
            $('.container').append('<div id="two"></div>'); 
            $('#two').load('loader.php?page='+$page+'&load=0');
            $('#tree').remove();
        }
        if($n==1){
            $('.container').append('<div id="tree"></div>');    
            $('#tree').load('loader.php?page='+$page+'&load=0');
            $('#one').remove();
        }
        if($n==2){
            $('.container').append('<div id="one"></div>'); 
            $('#one').load('loader.php?page='+$page+'&load=0');
            $('#two').remove();
            $n=-1;
        }
        $n=$n+1;
    }
```

Он как бы рабочий. Когда прокрутка достигает низа страницы - добавляется блок, загружается в него инфа и удаляется самый верхний их трех. Беда в том, что в момент удаления прокрутка скачет (из-за этого автоматом достигает низа страницы и выполняется следующий пункт), но нужно достичь плавности работы. Сам код, в принципе можно и не читать, вопрос в следующем - можно ли как-то удалять блоки из DOM не нарушая прокрутки?

Comment: transition ставить не пробовали?

Comment: А зачем их пересоздавать каждый раз? Почему просто не менять их местами?

Comment: Не обязательно их удалять. Их можно перемещать и заменять в них информацию с помощью CSS transform: translate3d

Comment: zhenyab, можно еще как карусельку сделать )

Comment: по сути каруселька и получается

Comment: Спасибо за мысль, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дивы `.one`, `.two`, `.three` позиционируйте абсолютно. Задайте для `.container` фиксированную высоту (изначально равную сумме высот дивов) c `overflow:none`.
При скроле удаляете один из дивов, добавляете новый в конец и увеличиваете высоту контэйнера.